# how can I upload multiple images with expo?

Tags: react-native, expo

it is possible to upload several pictures with expo ? I searched the whole time but unfortunately couldn't find anything

thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by `upload`..You mean `Sending to Server (Backend)` ??

Answer (score 0):

I believe so. Just try the following:

```
<View>
<Image
   src="http:url"
   style={{height: 250, width: 250}}
/>
<Text>Some Text here</Text>
<Image
   src="http:url"
   style={{height: 250, width: 250}}
/>
<Text>Some more text</Text>
</View>


If that doesn't work for you, try putting the second image in a new View.
```

Comment: I mean file upload. Image picker ^^

Answer (score 0):

Create an array of `file` URIs..

```
const files = [
    file://.....,
    file://.....,
    file://.....,
]
```

Now create a function to send files to server like this

```
  const SendFiles = async () => {
    try {
      const form = new FormData();
      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        form.append("Files[]", {
          name: "SampleImage.png", // or whatever that URI's file name is
          uri: files[i].uri,
          type: "image/png", // whatever the file extension is there for that particular file URI
        });
      }

      // Perform a Post request here by adding this form inside the body
    } catch (error) {}
  };
```